# MissingMemberException when trying to use LINQ on subproject Tasks

Tags: vb.net, linq, office-interop, ms-project

I am working on a Microsoft Project add-in in VB.NET. Each Project is of type `Project`, and has its own list of Tasks that are of type `Tasks` and they contain lots of tasks of type `Task`. Microsoft Project has an option to add other Project files inside of it as Subprojects. These subprojects are of type `Subproject`, but they have a property `SourceProject` which is of type `Project`. Meaning, you should be able to access each subprojects `Tasks` as if it were a regular `Project` type through `Project.Subprojects(0).SourceProject.Tasks`.

I tried using LINQ to filter out some tasks on a `Project`. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898380/my-enumerable-class-does-not-work-with-linq-statements-like-where-in-c-sharp) answer very helpful, and I managed to do it successfully without any errors. In the below code `ThisProject` is of type `Project`:

```
Dim tasksWithResources = ThisProject.Tasks.Cast(Of MSProject.Task).Where(Function(x) x.ResourceNames <> "")
```

However, when I try doing the exact same thing when iterating through subprojects, I get a `MemberMissingException`:

```
For Each subproject In ThisProject.Subprojects
    Dim subprojectTasksWithResources = subproject.SourceProject.Tasks.Cast(Of MSProject.Task).Where(Function(x) x.ResourceNames <> "")
Next
```

I tried accessing the subprojects tasks by simply assigning them to a variable thinking that there were no `Tasks` in that subproject. But it was successful. So even if I write it like this (which I know is the same thing as the code block above), I get the `MemberMissingException` on the row where I use `Cast`:

```
For Each subproject In ThisProject.Subprojects
    Dim tsks = subproject.SourceProject.Tasks
    Dim subprojectTasksWithResources = tsks.Cast(Of MSProject.Task).Where(Function(x) x.ResourceNames <> "")
Next
```

This is the error message I'm getting:
`Public member 'Cast' on type 'Tasks' not found.`

**Edit:**
I understand that an easy workaround is not using LINQ, but rather iterating through the object with a `For Each`, but I'm curious why LINQ is not working.

Comment: You must be using late binding if the compiler allows that through until run time. Are you able to turn `Option Strict On` and use early binding? If you have written lots of code with `Option Strict Off` then there may be lots of late binding and implicit conversions but you should always avoid late binding unless you specifically need it.

Comment: FYI, I have deleted my answer because I misread your question and thought that you were trying to get the `Tasks` of the subproject itself rather than the `SourceProject` of the subproject.

Comment: What you describe does seem very strange. I would be using the debugging tools to compare objects and their types to see if I can see a discrepancy, e.g. compare `ThisProject` to `subproject.SourceProject` to see whether they are the same object and the same type. If `ReadOnly` is `True` on `subproject`, maybe they aren't.

Comment: `Cast(Of T)` is used to convert `IEnumerable` to `IEnumerable(Of T)`.  The missing member exception would suggest that the second instance of `Tasks` isn't an `IEnumerable`.  Note that as I recall, `IEnumerable` is not strictly necessary to use `For Each ... Next`, it's merely necessary to have a functionally equivalent interface (that is, it has members with the same names, arguments, returns, and behavior is `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might be that the subproject's tasks are not yet loaded.

Try forcing the project to load by accessing a task. For example:

```
For Each s As MSProject.Subproject In ThisProject.Subprojects
    Dim tempTsk As MSProject.Task = s.Tasks(1)
    Dim subprojectTasksWithResources = s.SourceProject.Tasks.Cast(Of MSProject.Task).Where(Function(x) x.ResourceNames <> "")
Next
```

I have used the following code in my add-ins to force the subprojects to load. It works well, but I think the above code might be all you need.

```
Friend Sub ShowAllTasks()
    ' expands all tasks to make sure all collapsed subprojects are loaded
    With ProjApp
        .SummaryTasksShow(True)
        .FilterApply("All Tasks")
        .SelectAll()
        .OutlineShowAllTasks()
        .SelectBeginning()
    End With
End Sub
```

Note: this presumes the current view is a task view.

P.S. Use a different variable name for your subprojects as `subproject` is the name of an object.